# Nginx config not working on my docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I'm new with dockers.

I'm studying this docker-compose.yml in order to create a this three containers for webserver, workspace for my laravel and the db. And I'm understanding most of it.

It builds just fine but on localhost I get the nginx default page, not my laravel public folder.

I have a app.conf file inside of /nginx/conf.d/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

```
version: '3.2'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp-workspace
    container_name: myapp-workspace
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: "/var/www"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: myapp-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: myapp-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
        - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
        - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Your nginx config set the root folder to /var/www/public but your Dockerfile copies all files to /var/www. Have you exec into the Docker container and see if you find your app files into the folders above?

Comment: Yes, I have. Thanks for the reply, I've found the problem. Still try and error is no good way to learn haha, I still have so many questions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Seems that the "app" part on this line "fastcgi_pass app:9000;" on my app.conf should be the name of my workspace container.

So like this it works.

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/public;
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass myapp-workspace:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

}